# Bridging LAN and WIFI using netplan not working and killing AP

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan, network-bridge

I'm trying to extend my local LAN network via WiFi and would like all devices in the same network. The setup is as follows:

- DHCP/DNS server running inside the LAN
- separate PC linked to the LAN, with WIFI capability (sadly it's not an option, to have the DHCP/DNS server running on this machine)

Since I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, I'm trying to use netplan to set everything up. Here's my `.conf` file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.10/24]
      gateway: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.2, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      access-points:
        "MyWifi":
          mode: ap
          password: "DONTLOOK"
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces: [enp2s0, wlp1s0]
```

Now, running the two network separately, i.e without the bridges section, everything works. With dnsmasq activated I can connect to the access point.

However, I can't seem to get the bridge working. Even worse is, as soon as the bridge gets activated, access to the AP is no longer possible.

Does anybody have an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly not yet, still working on it...If you have any ideas...

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1769668

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember running into the same issue about a year ago, and am sad to find out this is still a problem. In my working configuration:

- I keep the default `networkd` as the renderer.
- In Netplan config, treat wlan0 as ethernet, and don't configure AP at all.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
#  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces:
        - eth0
        - wlan0
      optional: true
```

- I manually created `wlan0.config` for hostapd, and made a parameterised instance - `systemctl enable hostapd@wlan0`. The installation on 19.10 is configured so that it starts as soon as the interface becomes available for configuration.

Answer (score -1):

This is my YAML file; it's working.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
    switchports:
      match:
        name: wlp2s0 # replace with your interface name
      mtu: 1280
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      access-points:
        "M93p":
          password: "[put the password here]"
          mode: ap
          band: 2.4GHz
          channel: 10
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.60/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.240
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.240
          - 192.168.1.1
      interfaces:
        - switchports
        - eno1
```

Comment: Computer configuration like LAN addresses and interface names vary by user. Perhaps you could instead compare your file with the nonworking one, and post the comparison results instead, to catch any errors that OP may have made?